# with jquery get values from input with name structure

Tags: jquery

text input have names with arrays styles (name="post[2][id]"). I need get this values in jQuery script with this structure names. So that I can work as a normal array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var data = {};
    data['post'] = {};

    var fields = $("#user input");

    $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
        data[$(field).attr('name')] = $(field).val();
    });

    console.log(data);
});


<div id="user">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Joy" />
    <input type="text" name="post[1][id]" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="post[1][name]" value="test" />
    <input type="text" name="post[2][id]" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="post[2][name]" value="test 2" />
</div>
```

Now my name add like string in data variable, so this is very bad.
I need this:

```
alert(data.post.1.id) // 2
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for help with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Without extending jQuery's selector, you can make use of jQuery's `contains` selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Like this

`$('input[name*="["][name*="]"]')`

Translated it English, it means, *give me the `input`s where the name contains `[` and `]`*

---

Long answer:

The short answer should pragmatically be adequate.

But FYI...

The duplicate use of `[name...]` is because of one downside, we cannot use wildcards in such selectors.

Another downside is they do not define strict order of occurrence. E.g. a name of `post]1[` will also be matched.

If you really need to ensure the name has the correct string pattern, you can extend jQuery's selector to perform Regex operations for stricter selection rules.

Here's a good one: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/